# visualize DASK task graphs

Tags: python, dask

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/spec.html) and created a graph like so:

```
from dask.threaded import get

from operator import add

dsk = {
   'x': 1,
   'y': 2,
   'z': (add, 'x', 'y'),
   'w': (sum, ['x', 'y', 'z'])
}

get(dsk, "w")
```

That works and I get the desired output. How can I visualize the computational graph? The *visualize* method expects a DASK object and I only a have a dictionary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`dask.visualize` works on [Dask Collections](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/#familiar-user-interface) -- the [API docs here](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#dask.visualize) mention `args` need to be a "dask object", which means a Dask Collection (I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8640) to improve the docs!).

So, if you wrap your task graph `dsk` in a Collection, you should be able to `visualize` it:

```py
import dask

from operator import add
from dask.threaded import get
from dask.delayed import Delayed

dsk = {
   'x': 1,
   'y': 2,
   'z': (add, 'x', 'y'),
   'w': (sum, ['x', 'y', 'z'])
}

# wrapping dsk in a Dask Collection (Delayed)
delayed_dsk = Delayed("w", dsk)

# call visualize as usual
delayed_dsk.visualize()

# Or,
dask.visualize(delayed_dsk)
```

[image: task graph visualized]

Answer (score 0):

Pass your graph to `dask.vizulalize()`:

```
from dask.threaded import get
from operator import add
import dask

dsk = {
   'x': 1,
   'y': 2,
   'z': (add, 'x', 'y'),
   'w': (sum, ['x', 'y', 'z'])
}

get(dsk, "w")

dask.visualize(dsk)
```

See "[Vizualize task graphs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/graphviz.html)" documentation chapter as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

That creates an empty image.

Comment: Do you have graphviz installed? There should be both graphviz system library installed and python graphviz library.

Comment: Yes. When I use tried to visualize the returns of a @delayed function the graph looks as expected.

Comment: I would try to update the versions of affected libraries: dask, python graphviz module and system graphviz library. Seems like some discrepancy between participant components.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect for recent versions of dask. As described in [this issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8883) this stopped working in version 2021.12.0.
The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70898095/1588847) from @pavithraes reflects the same workaround (tho it's less than ideal!).